# Share variable through ruby processes

Tags: ruby, multithreading, process, fork

I'm writing a gem, where I have to fork two processes which are starting two webrick servers. I want to start this servers through a class method from a base class, because there should only be this two servers running, not multiple ones. During runtime, I want to call some methods on this two servers to change variables.

My problem is, that I can't access the instance variables of the forks, through a class method of the base class. Furthermore, I can't use threads inside my base class, because under the hood I'm using another library which is not thread safe. So I have to fork each server to it's own process.

I tried it with class variables, like `@@server`. But when I try to access this variables through the base class, it's `nil`. I read that sharing class variables among forks isn't possible in Ruby, am I right?

So, is there any other way around this? I thought of using a singleton, but I'm not sure if this is the best idea.

Comment: [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: Just a link is a little bit less ;) I know inter process communication, but do I really have to implement a XML interface, or deal with system specific protocolls to achieve this? I thought, maybe there is a "ruby-way" to do this

Comment: @23tux: Ruby processes are separate, IPC is (at the top level) the only way to solve your problem. There are plenty of Ruby gems that could help though. You could probably just `Marshal` your data to disk - all you'd need to add is some locking (to avoid partial reads/writes), and keep an eye on performance. Next up might be marshalling to a local `memcached` to avoid touching the disk . . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you fork a process then the child and parent processes's memory are separated, so you cannot share variables between them directly. So a singleton class will not work in your case.

The solution is [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), Ruby supports both [pipes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe) and [sockets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/index.html), which are the two most used forms of IPC, at least on *NIX. Ruby also supports [distributed objects](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/drb/rdoc/index.html), if you need a more transparent interface.

What you chose depends on the job. If you know you want to split you processes over several computers at some point, go with sockets or drb. If not go with pipes.

[Here's a short introduction to pipes in Ruby](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766091-introduction-to-ipc-in-ruby)